# Checking if iTunes is shuffling is not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, itunes, shuffle

I'm developing a Mac App and I need to check if Itunes (11.0) is shuffling my music so, to check that, I'm using `iTunes.h` and the following code:

```
if([iTunes.currentPlaylist shuffle]){
    NSLog(@"yes");
}else{
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

Even though I have my iTunes shuffling, it always outputs "no". 

Any ideas why is this happening or am I checking it the wrong way?

Comment: Are you using the correct `iTunesPlaylist` object?

Comment: what do you mean? the property `currentPlaylist` does all the work of getting the current playlist iTunes is playing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good luck with that.

I reported a bug about a month ago, like tons of other developers.
Didn't hear anything, and probably won't.

Like DigiMonk wrote, it a change in iTunes 11, but they don't update their API.

Comment: so theres like no way of doing it? even with custom applescripts?

Comment: I didn't find any. Except for using UI Scripting, which is buggy.

Comment: May be the iTunes Gurus at Apple forgot to invite their own Apple Script Gurus to that famous party everyone still speaks of LOL

Answer (score 3):

This I know: in iTunes 11 some things changed. One of them is that the "shuffle"-option is playlist-independent...

Comment: I assume iTunes' AppleScript Dictionary is not updated yet. It has something like "song repeat" but that gives also always "off" and it still has to address a playlist which can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

A long way around for the time being might be to listen for NSDistributedNotifications and check whether the attributes for the currently playing track match the previous or next one. It's not the cleanest solution, but it should work if what's being shuffled is an album or artist. Just check whether the track numbers go in sequence, or if the artist name is the same, etc.